# Position vs Destination Rectangle

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm new to programming, and I finally delved into XNA/MonoGame for wanting to practice coding game logic.

I'd like to know what the difference is between a Position (Vector2) and a Destination Rectangle (Rectangle), when it comes to positioning a sprite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is: the Vector2 positions the sprite at the X,Y coordinates, while Destination rectangle fills the sprite to *fit* that rectangle.

More advanced answer:

Sprites are in reality quads made up of two triangles, since underneath all this graphics stuff 3D routines are used. So both Draw methods transfer the sprite to a quad. This quad is basically a rectangle.

So what the Vector2 variant does is *create* a DestinationRectangle internally like this when calling SpriteBatch.Draw():

```
destrect = new Rectangle((int)V2.X, (int)V2.Y, Texture.Width, Texture.Height);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I noticed that the 8th overload in SpriteBatch.Draw() includes both a Vector2 and a DestinationRectangle for the same purpose--to display the position. Does that mean I must set either one of them to null?

Comment: In the overload that takes both vector2 *and* rectangle, the rectangle is the *source* rectangle. It means the sprite will be draw only using that section from the Texture.